# C Bit Utility Functions: Popcount, Trailing Zeros Count, Reverse All Bits

Tags: c, bitwise

Here are some utility bitwise functions for 64 bit integers. I have independently derived `inv64` (inverse all bits) and `pcnt64` (count bits set to 1) myself, though I am sure someone else has before, so this is nothing new. But `ctz64` (count trailing zero bits) is a modified version of [Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right in parallel (Bit Twiddling Hacks)](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel).

```c
uint64_t inv64(uint64_t n) {
    n = (n & 0x5555555555555555ULL) << 1 | n >> 1 & 0x5555555555555555ULL;
    n = (n & 0x3333333333333333ULL) << 2 | n >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333ULL;
    n = (n & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL) << 4 | n >> 4 & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL;
    n = (n & 0xFF00FF00FF00FFULL) << 8 | n >> 8 & 0xFF00FF00FF00FFULL;
    n = (n & 0xFFFF0000FFFFULL) << 16 | n >> 16 & 0xFFFF0000FFFFULL;
    return n << 32 | n >> 32;
}
uint8_t pcnt64(uint64_t n) {
    n = (n & 0x5555555555555555ULL) + (n >> 1 & 0x5555555555555555ULL);
    n = (n & 0x3333333333333333ULL) + (n >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333ULL);
    n = (n & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL) + (n >> 4 & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
    n = (n & 0xFF00FF00FF00FFULL) + (n >> 8 & 0xFF00FF00FF00FFULL);
    n = (n & 0xFFFF0000FFFFULL) + (n >> 16 & 0xFFFF0000FFFFULL);
    return (uint8_t)n + (uint8_t)(n >> 32);
}
uint64_t ctz64(uint64_t n) {
    n &= -(int64_t)n;
    return (!(n & 0xFFFFFFFFULL) << 5 |
            !(n & 0xFFFF0000FFFFULL) << 4 |
            !(n & 0xFF00FF00FF00FFULL) << 3 |
            !(n & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL) << 2 |
            !(n & 0x3333333333333333ULL) << 1 |
            !(n & 0x5555555555555555ULL)) + !n;
}
```

Comment: Use some parentheses. >> and & besides each other is to me as good as a bug.

Comment: @gnasher729 `+-*/` > `>>` > `&` > `^` > `|`

Comment: Not an answer but you might find [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) very useful and/or interesting.

Comment: @Pryftan I do. They were the inspiration for `ctz64()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These look familiar to me, but they are apparently "different enough" that GCC and Clang [fail to recognize them as idioms](https://godbolt.org/z/fnf34691W). Well, the bit-reversal comes out about as well as can be expected on x64 (GCC and Clang both managed to use `bswap`), but not the other two.

If I make a couple of changes to `pcnt64` then suddenly GCC and Clang recognize it:

```
uint8_t pcnt64(uint64_t n) {
    n = n - ((n >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL);
    n = (n & 0x3333333333333333ULL) + (n >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333ULL);
    n = (n + (n >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL;
    return (n * 0x0101010101010101ULL) >> 56;
}
```

[Gets compiled into](https://godbolt.org/z/esTbxhW4T)

```
popcnt64:
        xor     eax, eax
        popcnt  rax, rdi
        ret
```

Although when compiling with a different compiler and/or targeting a different platform, this can work out poorly - for example on an embedded platform that lacks both a built-in popcnt instruction and also a hardware multiplier. As is commonly the case, the same code is not the best for all platforms. You could do some `#ifdef`-based selection between alternative implementations, or just decide which platforms you care about the most.

I don't know what portable code to write such that a `tzcnt` instruction comes out. If you don't care about portability so much, there's `_tzcnt_u64` (from `immintrin.h`) which is at least "portable across compilers", though not across different CPUs. As a "dual" to that there is `__builtin_ctzll` which is a GCC/Clang builtin (maybe seen in some other random compilers, but not MSVC) but supported across different CPUs (note that it does not deal gracefully with the case where the input is zero).

In `n &= -(int64_t)n;` you should not be casting to `int64_t` to do the negation. Paradoxically that creates the potential for UB, while negating an unsigned integer is completely safe (with no edge cases) and does exactly what you need it to do. Though to silence some incorrect warnings, you may need to subtract from zero instead of negate.

There is an alternative trailing-zero-counting strategy that may be better in some cases (`popcnt` instructions are more widely available across different CPUs, and seem to be easier to get out of a compiler too): make a mask of the trailing zeroes and then `popcnt` that. [For example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yada737P7):

```
uint64_t ctz64(uint64_t n) {
    return pcnt64(~n & (n - 1));
}
```

`~n & (n - 1)` is a trailing-bit-manipulation idiom, see [manipulating rightmost bits](http://programming.sirrida.de/programming.html#rightmost_bits).

Clang even managed to make a `tzcnt` from that; GCC's more literal interpretation is not bad either.

Comment: If you're going to `#ifdef` anything, you'd probably want to `#ifdef __GNUC__` and define these as `__builtin_popcountll` and so on.  GNU C `__builtin_clzll` / `ctzll` are for `unsigned long long` which is normally the same as `uint64_t` but you could check.  More importantly, those functions produce an undefined result for an input of `0`.  (Not UB but not a guaranteed `64` like `_tzcnt_u64` / `_lzcnt_u64`).  That allows them to compile to a single `bsf` / `bsr` instruction without checking for 0, unlike C++20 `std::countr_zero` / `countl_zero`.  (`__builtin_clzll(x|1)` caps it at 63)

Comment: Without being compiler dependent: Check if __has_builtin is defined, then check #if __has_builtin (__builtin_popcountll). So compilers that are not GNUC can implement this as well.

Comment: harold, At a future time `(n * 0x0101010101010101ULL) >> 56` may incur a 128-bit multiplication as `long long` may be 128-bit.  OTOH, Should that occur, I hope such a machine to optimize to a speedier 64-bit multiplication given the `uint84_t` return type.  `(n * 0x0101010101010101U) >> 56` and `(n * UINT64_C(0x0101010101010101)) >> 56` avoid a future 128 bit multiply.

Answer (score 2):

Small stuff:

---

**Missing include**

Add `#include <stdint.h>`.

**Inverse?**

Rather than *inverse*, which can sound like a bit-wise complement, consider *bit_reverse* or the like.

```
// inv64()
bit_reverse64()
```

**What the `LL`?**

Minor: None of constants *need* the `LL` suffix in OP's code as all are `&` masks with a `uint64_t`.
The `U` remains useful to avoid mixed sign-ness is the operations.

Today `long long` is commonly 64-bit.  It maybe wider in the future.

With fixed width types, when wanting to insure a constant accommodates a certain width, code can use `(U)INTN_C` as in `UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF)`.

**Minor: `()`**

Consider [Use some parentheses. >> and & besides each other is to me as good as a bug.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288007/c-bit-utility-functions-popcount-trailing-zeros-count-reverse-all-bits#comment573703_288007) .

Not needed if the anticipated readers of code know the C's [order of precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) rules well.
After many decades, I still need to review the levels (15) from time-to-time for the less popular precedence rules.

**Minor: Why 2 casts?**

I suspect a good compiler will emit efficient code either way.

```
(uint8_t)n + (uint8_t)(n >> 32);
vs.
(uint8_t) (n + (n >> 32));
```

Note that with `(uint8_t)n + (uint8_t)(n >> 32)`, Both `(uint8_t)` operands of the `+` are converted to `unsigned` before the addition.  The final sum then incurs a silent `(uint8_t)` on the return which may warn on some pedantic compilers.